# Is there a dependency/interconnection between DENSE_RANK() and LEAD() function?

Tags: sql

I am working on [Game Play Analysis 4](https://leetcode.com/problems/game-play-analysis-iv/) on Leetcode

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT PLAYER_ID FROM (
    SELECT 
        PLAYER_ID,
        EVENT_DATE,
        LEAD(EVENT_DATE,1) OVER(PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID) AS NEXT_DAY,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) AS LOGIN_RANK 
        FROM ACTIVITY) A
    WHERE NEXT_DAY - EVENT_DATE = 1
    AND LOGIN_RANK=1  
)
```

Output I get is

```
{"headers": ["PLAYER_ID"], "values": [[67]]}
```

After making a small difference, i.e. changing the order of `DENSE_RANK()` and `LEAD()` function I get a completely different output.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT PLAYER_ID FROM (
    SELECT 
        PLAYER_ID,
        EVENT_DATE, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY event_date) AS LOGIN_RANK,
        LEAD(EVENT_DATE,1) OVER(PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID) AS NEXT_DAY
        FROM ACTIVITY) A
WHERE NEXT_DAY - EVENT_DATE = 1
AND LOGIN_RANK=1
        )
```

I get a completely different output, which is the correct one.

```
{"headers": ["PLAYER_ID"], "values": [[4], [9], [12], [19], [28], [39], [48], [59], [60], [67], [86], [98]]}
```

Can anyone help me explain how is changing/reordering the function in SQL making a difference in output, is there a dependency between two function? I am not looking forward to the solution of the question, I am trying to understand how is reordering these two functions making a difference in the output

Input is in Json Format

```
{"headers":{"Activity":["player_id","device_id","event_date","games_played"]},"rows":{"Activity":[[5,17,"2019-01-17",44],[31,43,"2019-01-21",41],[52,89,"2019-03-09",44],[14,154,"2019-02-13",87],[96,46,"2019-03-22",77],[73,131,"2019-03-19",70],[49,106,"2019-02-13",80],[12,189,"2019-01-15",13],[40,151,"2019-01-19",4],[63,196,"2019-02-23",74],[37,86,"2019-01-22",38],[60,41,"2019-03-07",46],[60,162,"2019-01-12",8],[9,81,"2019-01-28",88],[83,48,"2019-02-15",6],[97,85,"2019-03-30",0],[21,87,"2019-01-18",16],[77,170,"2019-02-17",41],[37,192,"2019-03-04",37],[76,141,"2019-01-04",3],[89,48,"2019-02-26",80],[48,3,"2019-03-25",70],[68,165,"2019-02-07",12],[63,200,"2019-03-11",73],[84,126,"2019-02-04",73],[57,23,"2019-02-16",16],[36,19,"2019-02-27",54],[73,7,"2019-03-28",54],[17,172,"2019-03-14",67],[46,143,"2019-01-28",43],[56,79,"2019-01-08",99],[31,44,"2019-03-09",78],[58,48,"2019-03-08",46],[87,111,"2019-02-20",17],[3,10,"2019-02-20",31],[44,19,"2019-01-12",37],[95,89,"2019-03-07",4],[7,151,"2019-03-04",66],[66,16,"2019-03-01",73],[37,132,"2019-03-08",52],[26,116,"2019-02-24",34],[7,126,"2019-03-09",64],[98,170,"2019-03-05",23],[91,50,"2019-01-26",32],[47,160,"2019-02-12",99],[52,83,"2019-03-23",35],[45,106,"2019-01-28",39],[34,94,"2019-02-24",60],[75,110,"2019-03-13",66],[77,131,"2019-01-11",12],[12,68,"2019-03-22",68],[40,97,"2019-02-11",62],[91,86,"2019-03-09",28],[8,42,"2019-03-30",99],[14,161,"2019-03-28",50],[77,148,"2019-01-22",15],[100,87,"2019-01-13",42],[86,94,"2019-03-24",58],[23,26,"2019-02-04",94],[80,57,"2019-02-25",96],[98,48,"2019-02-18",48],[87,115,"2019-02-25",91],[30,6,"2019-02-07",62],[52,148,"2019-02-19",73],[5,178,"2019-03-04",93],[69,120,"2019-03-23",79],[95,76,"2019-03-26",50],[22,121,"2019-02-28",25],[65,96,"2019-01-31",86],[93,196,"2019-02-23",76],[63,12,"2019-02-25",89],[28,96,"2019-02-25",91],[3,6,"2019-02-17",10],[25,179,"2019-03-26",34],[91,17,"2019-03-30",0],[1,12,"2019-03-10",39],[69,7,"2019-03-12",33],[10,153,"2019-03-21",49],[41,98,"2019-02-06",70],[6,88,"2019-03-07",23],[46,81,"2019-03-10",64],[17,21,"2019-02-09",70],[66,151,"2019-03-07",25],[27,38,"2019-03-11",80],[84,91,"2019-03-19",83],[18,159,"2019-03-09",72],[72,188,"2019-02-17",5],[24,134,"2019-01-08",23],[28,190,"2019-01-04",68],[71,166,"2019-03-20",13],[59,156,"2019-03-03",26],[88,105,"2019-02-21",5],[42,55,"2019-01-01",46],[55,97,"2019-03-08",76],[1,3,"2019-01-03",16],[28,4,"2019-02-22",50],[63,148,"2019-01-01",66],[62,18,"2019-01-10",56],[8,160,"2019-02-07",52],[13,17,"2019-01-19",49],[27,91,"2019-01-15",78],[22,152,"2019-03-14",33],[73,56,"2019-02-16",25],[80,154,"2019-01-31",29],[4,12,"2019-01-04",34],[7,88,"2019-02-08",8],[66,42,"2019-01-02",48],[99,162,"2019-01-01",88],[19,117,"2019-02-28",86],[54,127,"2019-01-01",11],[67,102,"2019-01-19",83],[69,106,"2019-01-30",16],[85,129,"2019-02-02",97],[62,178,"2019-03-06",39],[87,38,"2019-01-11",12],[66,38,"2019-03-04",46],[93,175,"2019-02-12",55],[68,157,"2019-01-03",98],[38,157,"2019-02-21",52],[65,199,"2019-03-26",72],[61,167,"2019-03-01",55],[20,92,"2019-02-15",30],[61,45,"2019-02-17",86],[77,178,"2019-01-26",52],[34,61,"2019-03-16",54],[7,185,"2019-02-21",86],[8,91,"2019-03-03",10],[32,152,"2019-03-03",46],[83,5,"2019-02-10",54],[49,132,"2019-01-10",57],[32,56,"2019-03-23",13],[48,85,"2019-03-15",26],[50,23,"2019-01-11",49],[63,33,"2019-03-08",29],[14,115,"2019-02-12",85],[7,71,"2019-01-04",45],[57,126,"2019-02-17",97],[3,172,"2019-03-19",30],[76,147,"2019-03-26",19],[82,97,"2019-03-26",78],[84,51,"2019-02-06",91],[66,39,"2019-02-27",7],[69,168,"2019-02-16",42],[29,196,"2019-02-13",7],[90,11,"2019-02-07",11],[66,146,"2019-03-11",44],[90,125,"2019-01-03",71],[25,52,"2019-01-08",71],[42,156,"2019-02-28",97],[19,7,"2019-01-18",85],[16,135,"2019-03-08",16],[83,146,"2019-01-07",47],[67,46,"2019-03-14",73],[100,51,"2019-02-17",29],[67,112,"2019-01-11",9],[25,35,"2019-02-21",89],[65,54,"2019-03-30",55],[31,164,"2019-01-27",1],[49,75,"2019-03-22",96],[60,52,"2019-03-23",59],[65,16,"2019-03-12",70],[40,20,"2019-01-02",76],[24,93,"2019-01-20",42],[59,168,"2019-03-09",83],[7,174,"2019-01-18",15],[85,163,"2019-01-19",44],[69,126,"2019-01-06",69],[72,159,"2019-02-18",84],[19,37,"2019-03-10",3],[8,24,"2019-01-22",92],[63,111,"2019-03-09",0],[69,86,"2019-02-21",72],[87,100,"2019-03-03",31],[29,12,"2019-01-07",70],[88,111,"2019-03-04",84],[100,180,"2019-03-24",55],[57,197,"2019-02-14",60],[57,14,"2019-02-09",79],[59,60,"2019-02-10",49],[40,179,"2019-03-09",17],[68,198,"2019-03-24",67],[98,23,"2019-01-17",75],[18,90,"2019-03-16",9],[57,19,"2019-03-20",13],[25,154,"2019-03-03",57],[34,20,"2019-03-14",1],[41,78,"2019-03-03",78],[27,80,"2019-02-27",96],[58,77,"2019-02-22",18],[89,104,"2019-02-03",97],[18,84,"2019-01-30",3],[33,71,"2019-01-24",43],[28,193,"2019-03-30",95],[83,118,"2019-02-04",19],[94,101,"2019-01-01",80],[35,128,"2019-01-01",72],[74,190,"2019-02-12",74],[56,125,"2019-03-19",33],[90,18,"2019-01-22",29],[69,146,"2019-02-22",20],[3,4,"2019-02-10",29],[76,70,"2019-02-06",40],[16,87,"2019-01-01",32],[22,91,"2019-01-12",73],[27,16,"2019-03-15",3],[27,167,"2019-02-23",42],[95,91,"2019-03-01",82],[8,19,"2019-03-29",31],[95,111,"2019-01-07",63],[49,140,"2019-02-18",29],[6,38,"2019-01-19",48],[4,26,"2019-03-01",51],[53,193,"2019-01-19",31],[91,103,"2019-01-18",60],[95,37,"2019-03-18",41],[43,157,"2019-01-10",45],[67,63,"2019-01-30",74],[10,99,"2019-03-02",64],[53,91,"2019-03-27",31],[30,28,"2019-01-27",2],[18,152,"2019-03-26",87],[86,1,"2019-02-15",37],[60,76,"2019-03-25",35],[85,7,"2019-01-16",74],[98,49,"2019-01-29",61],[13,67,"2019-02-06",8],[47,50,"2019-01-17",54],[72,148,"2019-01-28",78],[72,134,"2019-01-03",92],[40,168,"2019-03-29",46],[32,184,"2019-01-13",10],[56,129,"2019-02-19",97],[33,11,"2019-02-20",18],[79,95,"2019-03-23",20],[92,186,"2019-02-19",9],[77,63,"2019-03-01",72],[42,164,"2019-03-19",82],[2,74,"2019-02-27",47],[55,198,"2019-03-09",7],[49,167,"2019-03-01",41],[18,135,"2019-01-20",76],[30,86,"2019-01-22",64],[94,188,"2019-01-25",63],[73,11,"2019-02-17",69],[38,179,"2019-03-15",83],[70,147,"2019-01-21",95],[20,43,"2019-01-06",0],[24,35,"2019-03-05",81],[96,34,"2019-03-11",19],[95,198,"2019-01-21",96],[89,81,"2019-01-31",7],[100,46,"2019-02-03",38],[75,45,"2019-02-14",18],[30,170,"2019-02-11",43],[45,61,"2019-02-12",49],[97,181,"2019-03-18",52],[21,138,"2019-02-19",76],[14,45,"2019-01-11",39],[26,120,"2019-03-08",8],[50,48,"2019-03-13",11],[94,131,"2019-02-13",28],[93,115,"2019-01-07",5],[41,144,"2019-02-26",19],[18,146,"2019-02-26",45],[33,133,"2019-03-10",21],[47,200,"2019-01-26",54],[62,105,"2019-03-23",78],[91,56,"2019-01-24",35],[16,16,"2019-01-24",79],[46,114,"2019-02-17",70],[49,197,"2019-03-27",72],[18,77,"2019-03-30",95],[14,124,"2019-02-10",53],[58,160,"2019-01-18",85],[84,194,"2019-01-30",32],[93,118,"2019-02-25",61],[79,187,"2019-03-06",61],[37,84,"2019-03-07",91],[83,35,"2019-01-28",74],[66,121,"2019-02-23",73],[32,99,"2019-01-28",33],[39,131,"2019-01-04",74],[77,45,"2019-01-07",89],[36,74,"2019-01-06",64],[68,161,"2019-02-03",46],[13,8,"2019-02-17",72],[33,183,"2019-01-20",24],[43,181,"2019-02-03",83],[78,100,"2019-01-04",26],[21,158,"2019-01-27",14],[6,120,"2019-01-27",95],[50,27,"2019-01-29",1],[15,162,"2019-01-07",71],[41,24,"2019-01-15",80],[64,195,"2019-02-19",73],[69,135,"2019-01-20",18],[77,105,"2019-01-13",42],[71,125,"2019-03-16",42],[34,134,"2019-03-28",87],[37,57,"2019-01-17",45],[29,1,"2019-02-14",93],[45,187,"2019-03-13",59],[70,176,"2019-01-01",38],[52,90,"2019-02-14",30],[55,139,"2019-01-11",75],[8,30,"2019-03-23",37],[54,140,"2019-02-17",45],[10,55,"2019-02-12",75],[11,46,"2019-03-25",60],[13,81,"2019-01-21",70],[39,174,"2019-01-08",25],[34,148,"2019-02-02",48],[71,128,"2019-01-28",100],[19,120,"2019-03-09",54],[1,41,"2019-01-06",83],[48,144,"2019-01-31",23],[18,49,"2019-01-11",54],[56,49,"2019-02-20",61],[35,78,"2019-02-07",78],[38,30,"2019-02-14",57],[27,40,"2019-02-03",50],[5,156,"2019-03-02",76],[30,188,"2019-01-04",86],[87,131,"2019-02-15",20],[22,182,"2019-02-14",90],[19,15,"2019-03-30",26],[98,147,"2019-02-13",89],[78,84,"2019-02-16",79],[79,88,"2019-01-11",69],[21,41,"2019-01-15",39],[57,51,"2019-03-11",97],[28,10,"2019-03-09",58],[32,23,"2019-02-21",91],[94,170,"2019-03-22",68],[23,25,"2019-01-07",7],[8,58,"2019-02-28",92],[44,180,"2019-02-18",35],[53,53,"2019-03-30",15],[68,107,"2019-03-02",82],[97,123,"2019-03-08",53],[40,38,"2019-01-05",60],[45,106,"2019-01-04",13],[40,29,"2019-03-04",20],[31,130,"2019-02-07",1],[100,87,"2019-02-12",24],[80,105,"2019-03-05",62],[47,138,"2019-03-09",30],[4,28,"2019-03-17",27],[88,42,"2019-02-17",61],[32,15,"2019-01-23",21],[88,18,"2019-01-01",63],[8,98,"2019-03-18",16],[24,155,"2019-02-27",65],[46,6,"2019-02-08",8],[69,77,"2019-01-25",81],[34,18,"2019-02-27",11],[68,73,"2019-01-09",88],[76,13,"2019-01-21",73],[73,144,"2019-03-26",7],[84,101,"2019-01-12",98],[84,200,"2019-03-23",44],[89,27,"2019-02-08",37],[100,15,"2019-02-11",71],[99,122,"2019-03-22",53],[43,44,"2019-02-12",50],[58,94,"2019-03-09",6],[68,65,"2019-01-18",100],[7,34,"2019-01-30",84],[90,40,"2019-02-06",59],[31,54,"2019-02-13",60],[5,8,"2019-02-08",74],[91,36,"2019-01-09",66],[86,62,"2019-01-10",19],[42,150,"2019-01-25",40],[44,161,"2019-03-12",77],[8,179,"2019-01-26",28],[13,27,"2019-02-22",98],[87,120,"2019-01-04",15],[21,34,"2019-02-24",20],[53,109,"2019-03-15",89],[54,41,"2019-03-22",90],[8,175,"2019-03-22",6],[94,193,"2019-01-30",32],[40,81,"2019-01-12",17],[64,34,"2019-02-01",100],[68,3,"2019-03-21",32],[19,72,"2019-01-28",65],[94,5,"2019-01-24",59],[74,14,"2019-03-03",9],[69,18,"2019-01-16",54],[54,191,"2019-03-03",11],[20,14,"2019-03-05",68],[62,2,"2019-03-09",80],[70,25,"2019-03-08",34],[44,46,"2019-03-29",97],[28,67,"2019-02-01",55],[39,183,"2019-02-24",91],[92,53,"2019-01-28",86],[60,9,"2019-01-13",56],[90,140,"2019-01-20",80],[89,44,"2019-03-13",92],[30,137,"2019-03-25",55],[27,138,"2019-01-03",62],[84,18,"2019-03-03",28],[17,63,"2019-03-05",2],[54,187,"2019-01-07",3],[27,50,"2019-03-12",75],[69,122,"2019-02-08",40],[64,24,"2019-03-28",30],[25,194,"2019-01-14",63],[28,90,"2019-01-29",4],[86,49,"2019-03-07",66],[76,197,"2019-03-02",18],[64,48,"2019-01-02",74],[12,174,"2019-01-14",32],[48,154,"2019-01-08",76],[72,15,"2019-01-01",29],[59,62,"2019-03-11",89],[8,179,"2019-01-23",12],[9,86,"2019-02-24",48],[88,191,"2019-01-17",42],[52,103,"2019-01-25",37],[2,36,"2019-01-08",80],[100,114,"2019-03-03",16],[51,108,"2019-01-11",17],[19,174,"2019-02-25",44],[5,36,"2019-03-20",67],[70,101,"2019-02-05",28],[73,2,"2019-01-21",83],[3,80,"2019-03-20",12],[80,123,"2019-02-02",0],[61,103,"2019-02-01",81],[23,156,"2019-02-08",79],[21,154,"2019-03-29",58],[95,36,"2019-02-04",80],[90,148,"2019-02-26",97],[96,49,"2019-01-03",11],[99,76,"2019-01-27",78],[1,80,"2019-01-28",15],[46,152,"2019-01-27",87],[71,118,"2019-01-03",23],[94,92,"2019-03-04",16],[60,12,"2019-02-21",12],[91,153,"2019-02-26",15],[96,5,"2019-02-03",18],[26,151,"2019-03-14",95],[51,197,"2019-01-04",43],[34,123,"2019-01-08",0],[77,152,"2019-02-14",58],[70,115,"2019-01-30",98],[9,122,"2019-01-05",10],[81,184,"2019-02-11",83],[72,38,"2019-03-07",6],[80,141,"2019-03-07",76],[55,64,"2019-03-25",91],[22,132,"2019-02-09",50],[64,53,"2019-02-28",2],[29,97,"2019-02-03",73],[17,57,"2019-03-08",52],[32,165,"2019-01-26",26],[82,50,"2019-01-16",1],[91,45,"2019-03-11",68],[40,99,"2019-01-13",98],[90,96,"2019-01-24",60],[55,21,"2019-01-30",10],[89,80,"2019-01-18",43],[18,57,"2019-01-16",76],[43,118,"2019-03-02",86],[4,49,"2019-01-05",68],[19,168,"2019-01-21",11],[82,150,"2019-02-26",10],[72,180,"2019-01-24",66],[63,194,"2019-02-22",37],[24,43,"2019-02-13",11],[49,38,"2019-02-06",83],[93,114,"2019-02-05",55],[80,178,"2019-01-11",72],[31,53,"2019-02-02",49],[48,71,"2019-01-17",9],[21,157,"2019-01-10",1],[48,176,"2019-01-09",16],[5,8,"2019-01-12",18],[86,14,"2019-02-20",73],[25,56,"2019-01-12",93],[71,12,"2019-02-27",16],[64,71,"2019-03-23",72],[95,65,"2019-03-24",57],[56,45,"2019-02-03",73],[55,56,"2019-01-08",5],[79,195,"2019-01-31",91],[27,4,"2019-02-17",38],[23,170,"2019-02-25",0],[75,90,"2019-03-24",99],[4,167,"2019-03-02",90],[60,180,"2019-02-18",38],[23,35,"2019-03-16",70],[68,39,"2019-03-05",42],[98,132,"2019-02-21",16],[21,185,"2019-02-16",81],[71,123,"2019-02-23",61],[14,76,"2019-01-14",43],[53,18,"2019-01-16",61],[26,198,"2019-01-19",78],[96,133,"2019-01-08",76],[7,19,"2019-02-20",88],[21,183,"2019-03-28",93],[70,96,"2019-01-17",2],[81,46,"2019-03-11",51],[58,133,"2019-02-27",72],[69,27,"2019-01-27",40],[38,149,"2019-03-12",20],[3,69,"2019-01-21",32],[73,144,"2019-01-29",18],[48,8,"2019-01-30",28],[61,193,"2019-03-16",81],[64,54,"2019-02-05",84],[12,193,"2019-02-11",35],[29,113,"2019-02-24",40],[97,173,"2019-03-19",72],[41,86,"2019-03-06",12],[77,186,"2019-03-18",50],[10,145,"2019-03-27",89],[71,120,"2019-03-03",30],[6,117,"2019-03-16",60],[6,65,"2019-03-30",7],[33,172,"2019-01-23",22],[67,168,"2019-01-07",8],[86,96,"2019-01-31",38],[42,48,"2019-02-07",51],[37,104,"2019-03-24",68],[70,90,"2019-01-25",75],[37,141,"2019-03-26",92],[87,146,"2019-01-22",0],[73,193,"2019-01-07",74],[58,195,"2019-02-15",0],[38,122,"2019-01-27",17],[77,139,"2019-02-07",5],[80,33,"2019-01-20",76],[92,63,"2019-03-30",62],[79,148,"2019-03-30",79],[25,114,"2019-03-30",3],[20,168,"2019-01-27",51],[54,64,"2019-03-10",41],[76,47,"2019-03-30",8],[34,179,"2019-02-10",71],[2,172,"2019-02-17",92],[66,116,"2019-02-22",82],[40,163,"2019-02-15",54],[1,50,"2019-01-27",6],[79,80,"2019-01-26",49],[22,72,"2019-02-19",74],[97,120,"2019-03-17",76],[55,151,"2019-01-05",76],[91,5,"2019-02-11",91],[68,148,"2019-01-05",26],[23,28,"2019-01-28",6],[20,101,"2019-02-09",81],[95,144,"2019-01-27",10],[42,168,"2019-03-02",63],[67,4,"2019-01-08",32],[63,26,"2019-03-18",79],[8,109,"2019-01-28",41],[31,79,"2019-01-13",99],[13,4,"2019-02-20",17],[92,168,"2019-03-04",57],[85,32,"2019-03-30",92],[65,5,"2019-02-08",5],[68,84,"2019-03-19",49],[95,86,"2019-01-11",89],[13,121,"2019-01-20",75],[29,49,"2019-03-22",12],[3,45,"2019-02-02",24],[86,135,"2019-01-11",48],[25,198,"2019-02-20",34],[70,7,"2019-01-15",16],[1,5,"2019-03-14",68],[60,196,"2019-03-02",20],[6,141,"2019-01-26",66],[55,148,"2019-01-10",77],[1,120,"2019-01-01",40],[96,38,"2019-03-19",42],[97,155,"2019-01-25",40],[6,167,"2019-02-04",97],[28,192,"2019-02-08",31],[17,184,"2019-01-22",44],[92,147,"2019-03-14",32],[71,193,"2019-01-01",19],[74,25,"2019-02-16",66],[52,38,"2019-03-01",31],[81,97,"2019-01-23",12],[28,118,"2019-02-04",41],[20,96,"2019-02-03",20],[45,16,"2019-03-01",47],[85,9,"2019-03-11",64],[3,75,"2019-02-13",60],[62,126,"2019-02-24",68],[93,67,"2019-03-30",13],[77,18,"2019-03-20",5],[65,187,"2019-02-05",76],[53,91,"2019-03-16",8],[65,65,"2019-01-16",96],[68,114,"2019-03-23",31],[36,46,"2019-02-22",18],[32,89,"2019-02-19",94],[14,165,"2019-02-07",55],[15,17,"2019-01-26",19],[12,125,"2019-02-13",10],[19,82,"2019-01-17",67],[57,10,"2019-01-17",21],[8,125,"2019-01-15",73],[1,164,"2019-02-16",18],[57,172,"2019-03-17",49],[75,1,"2019-03-03",99],[35,185,"2019-03-15",41],[94,119,"2019-03-03",48],[13,4,"2019-03-14",13],[64,71,"2019-03-08",8],[63,76,"2019-02-08",44],[42,153,"2019-03-12",71],[6,112,"2019-01-14",1],[54,161,"2019-03-26",46],[53,48,"2019-01-21",77],[98,35,"2019-01-06",50],[10,99,"2019-01-20",38],[22,32,"2019-01-08",34],[36,174,"2019-03-27",1],[24,65,"2019-03-26",40],[18,144,"2019-03-11",50],[4,34,"2019-03-24",56],[64,163,"2019-03-25",86],[68,193,"2019-02-24",60],[45,74,"2019-02-09",4],[39,143,"2019-03-17",48],[51,199,"2019-02-12",60],[34,66,"2019-02-07",1],[86,188,"2019-03-16",54],[82,120,"2019-03-20",81],[71,3,"2019-03-02",89],[10,80,"2019-03-18",26],[25,34,"2019-02-07",74],[45,130,"2019-02-23",17],[92,136,"2019-01-10",95],[30,165,"2019-03-18",14],[93,11,"2019-01-02",32],[55,45,"2019-02-17",77],[23,185,"2019-01-23",30],[17,80,"2019-01-12",29],[16,3,"2019-02-13",3],[69,68,"2019-03-11",67],[37,16,"2019-03-25",61],[98,140,"2019-01-27",87],[90,186,"2019-02-02",31],[29,41,"2019-02-28",28],[93,125,"2019-02-01",96],[87,136,"2019-02-01",61],[60,194,"2019-02-04",68],[21,194,"2019-03-20",68],[94,181,"2019-02-07",15],[19,108,"2019-03-20",36],[35,139,"2019-03-28",60],[87,171,"2019-03-18",75],[66,164,"2019-02-21",10],[52,107,"2019-02-08",79],[79,101,"2019-03-04",5],[5,72,"2019-03-03",92],[96,7,"2019-02-26",70],[23,112,"2019-01-27",60],[33,37,"2019-03-17",69],[81,56,"2019-03-13",0],[91,171,"2019-01-19",1],[91,64,"2019-02-12",58],[95,194,"2019-01-02",86],[17,188,"2019-02-03",36],[48,57,"2019-02-26",25],[93,165,"2019-01-16",8],[92,3,"2019-01-16",5],[27,56,"2019-03-06",4],[36,10,"2019-03-29",31],[88,83,"2019-01-10",41],[32,78,"2019-02-02",84],[2,8,"2019-02-19",9],[50,67,"2019-03-29",72],[84,7,"2019-02-10",62],[96,78,"2019-02-27",93],[12,171,"2019-02-07",7],[57,156,"2019-02-19",37],[11,113,"2019-01-13",90],[7,10,"2019-03-26",30],[1,15,"2019-01-13",68],[43,156,"2019-03-13",27],[71,103,"2019-01-05",42],[89,37,"2019-02-01",84],[73,23,"2019-03-23",93],[54,57,"2019-01-19",13],[11,13,"2019-03-05",6],[81,62,"2019-01-16",62],[86,20,"2019-02-23",32],[99,43,"2019-01-25",39],[82,176,"2019-03-25",24],[40,17,"2019-02-02",57],[35,153,"2019-03-24",14],[38,174,"2019-02-07",13],[91,95,"2019-02-20",15],[99,187,"2019-01-18",99],[28,93,"2019-01-03",25],[83,46,"2019-01-12",50],[78,86,"2019-02-18",80],[83,27,"2019-01-02",88],[59,80,"2019-01-18",16],[66,114,"2019-02-04",31],[53,79,"2019-02-12",9],[44,27,"2019-01-27",44],[25,105,"2019-01-20",0],[20,159,"2019-01-23",40],[89,1,"2019-02-23",30],[37,104,"2019-03-06",92],[97,145,"2019-03-25",57],[42,117,"2019-02-16",63],[33,180,"2019-02-04",9],[16,106,"2019-02-18",73],[89,117,"2019-02-27",32],[28,101,"2019-01-05",88],[98,120,"2019-02-27",67],[73,182,"2019-01-03",17],[32,98,"2019-01-18",90],[49,87,"2019-02-22",8],[93,95,"2019-01-28",22],[70,123,"2019-03-27",5],[68,4,"2019-01-10",58],[38,64,"2019-02-20",74],[32,115,"2019-03-26",58],[65,78,"2019-02-26",74],[70,131,"2019-03-17",7],[22,112,"2019-01-28",91],[38,144,"2019-02-25",0],[9,127,"2019-01-04",55],[80,2,"2019-02-28",1],[2,85,"2019-03-01",90],[66,182,"2019-03-26",74],[41,190,"2019-02-04",45],[35,83,"2019-03-25",60],[100,179,"2019-03-10",32],[65,83,"2019-03-28",84],[28,157,"2019-02-06",64],[26,105,"2019-02-21",0],[94,37,"2019-01-15",81],[74,25,"2019-01-23",61],[55,88,"2019-01-07",77],[2,80,"2019-02-22",42],[78,73,"2019-03-01",62],[99,78,"2019-03-02",7],[19,137,"2019-03-25",73],[4,97,"2019-01-19",58],[80,189,"2019-03-22",77],[80,195,"2019-02-10",53],[25,69,"2019-03-18",52],[58,124,"2019-01-11",49],[23,64,"2019-03-26",55],[80,79,"2019-01-26",92],[68,151,"2019-01-20",98],[7,4,"2019-02-11",47],[42,39,"2019-03-08",84],[6,12,"2019-02-26",92],[99,64,"2019-01-13",76],[22,54,"2019-02-11",10],[92,178,"2019-01-23",97],[59,86,"2019-01-17",14],[7,142,"2019-01-26",8],[45,146,"2019-02-22",78],[19,90,"2019-03-26",59],[8,118,"2019-01-21",36],[16,157,"2019-01-20",33],[40,67,"2019-03-11",63],[71,105,"2019-02-03",75],[29,189,"2019-01-14",91],[12,38,"2019-01-12",27],[20,67,"2019-01-22",43],[54,91,"2019-03-25",63],[75,142,"2019-03-07",82],[39,159,"2019-03-11",18],[8,11,"2019-01-17",34],[30,186,"2019-02-10",20],[59,195,"2019-02-14",5],[74,124,"2019-01-16",13],[78,8,"2019-01-08",85],[86,25,"2019-03-04",37],[47,106,"2019-03-23",98],[99,147,"2019-02-21",36],[72,72,"2019-01-19",63],[69,6,"2019-02-13",41],[64,164,"2019-01-11",98],[94,175,"2019-03-21",88],[17,134,"2019-03-30",18],[46,173,"2019-01-18",73],[69,142,"2019-02-26",24],[44,138,"2019-02-24",31],[49,150,"2019-02-01",46],[40,97,"2019-03-24",85],[98,73,"2019-02-14",33],[2,51,"2019-03-20",24],[45,101,"2019-02-14",98],[40,187,"2019-01-22",85],[25,176,"2019-02-11",37],[94,74,"2019-02-01",57],[96,129,"2019-03-13",0],[77,163,"2019-02-20",100],[43,9,"2019-01-26",95],[68,148,"2019-02-13",4],[26,59,"2019-01-12",15],[41,75,"2019-02-11",99],[30,102,"2019-01-11",41],[3,168,"2019-01-15",27],[34,38,"2019-02-03",63],[27,44,"2019-01-31",23],[26,174,"2019-02-03",32],[95,96,"2019-02-03",44],[83,76,"2019-03-28",72],[20,165,"2019-01-02",64],[80,68,"2019-03-29",30],[10,14,"2019-02-23",10],[40,24,"2019-03-16",62],[25,4,"2019-02-03",48],[9,1,"2019-01-06",67],[6,122,"2019-02-20",92],[50,39,"2019-01-05",46],[28,153,"2019-01-26",59],[8,121,"2019-03-09",31],[23,176,"2019-01-25",21],[17,133,"2019-02-18",81],[45,52,"2019-03-11",24],[74,181,"2019-02-03",96],[97,177,"2019-02-25",0],[4,59,"2019-03-10",87],[84,173,"2019-03-24",42],[48,154,"2019-03-01",63],[44,13,"2019-01-25",42],[46,84,"2019-02-22",95],[84,68,"2019-02-03",74],[9,99,"2019-02-16",48],[43,62,"2019-03-22",61],[85,48,"2019-01-22",80],[45,184,"2019-03-15",1],[42,7,"2019-02-14",7],[32,199,"2019-02-13",96],[55,184,"2019-02-06",94],[1,161,"2019-02-21",8],[96,20,"2019-03-15",91],[13,123,"2019-02-01",90],[84,150,"2019-01-19",84],[96,31,"2019-02-25",28],[91,152,"2019-03-29",84],[64,12,"2019-01-25",8],[71,94,"2019-01-09",44],[56,161,"2019-03-04",69],[36,122,"2019-02-03",9],[100,54,"2019-03-22",75],[23,117,"2019-03-08",10],[32,148,"2019-01-17",4],[34,45,"2019-02-04",38],[98,39,"2019-01-05",43],[32,199,"2019-03-02",44],[96,198,"2019-03-05",48],[6,186,"2019-01-16",5],[74,130,"2019-03-04",75],[57,62,"2019-01-20",23],[2,80,"2019-01-04",90],[77,84,"2019-03-07",56],[26,22,"2019-03-01",14],[13,80,"2019-01-16",67],[23,91,"2019-02-10",21],[13,60,"2019-01-12",97],[51,107,"2019-01-19",1],[82,34,"2019-03-17",40],[12,166,"2019-01-11",46],[2,43,"2019-02-05",50],[39,9,"2019-03-09",97],[19,165,"2019-02-27",27],[72,142,"2019-01-16",85],[99,38,"2019-03-01",26],[28,4,"2019-03-29",55],[60,118,"2019-03-10",57],[75,74,"2019-03-16",78],[7,90,"2019-03-02",19],[35,115,"2019-03-07",73],[56,159,"2019-01-18",94],[69,166,"2019-01-19",71],[44,10,"2019-01-10",46],[13,178,"2019-03-15",71],[53,130,"2019-01-12",80],[49,93,"2019-03-23",79],[56,180,"2019-01-10",42],[82,172,"2019-01-05",94],[71,57,"2019-02-17",31],[22,146,"2019-02-12",15],[10,122,"2019-03-01",14],[22,136,"2019-03-04",4],[74,31,"2019-02-18",59],[4,66,"2019-02-09",61],[62,128,"2019-03-30",34],[58,187,"2019-02-16",81],[10,130,"2019-03-29",9],[16,47,"2019-01-17",86],[87,10,"2019-02-14",2],[44,71,"2019-01-23",81],[13,26,"2019-02-04",88],[37,80,"2019-02-09",28],[63,72,"2019-02-11",63],[38,200,"2019-03-25",29],[21,91,"2019-03-15",45],[86,6,"2019-03-01",22],[34,74,"2019-03-20",35],[63,137,"2019-03-05",26],[48,173,"2019-03-14",54],[59,36,"2019-02-13",75],[65,139,"2019-01-30",29],[66,186,"2019-02-16",73],[90,46,"2019-03-04",38],[7,82,"2019-03-21",27],[40,63,"2019-02-20",10],[86,40,"2019-03-19",51],[77,168,"2019-03-16",34],[77,92,"2019-02-09",31],[10,144,"2019-02-14",37],[76,28,"2019-01-30",85],[38,98,"2019-03-13",87],[77,127,"2019-02-26",89],[38,196,"2019-02-15",96],[6,200,"2019-01-24",0],[90,105,"2019-02-15",69],[3,200,"2019-01-13",55],[94,18,"2019-03-27",6],[92,79,"2019-03-13",74],[6,191,"2019-03-08",37],[84,129,"2019-03-12",18],[15,199,"2019-02-07",22],[55,134,"2019-03-11",53],[54,92,"2019-01-03",15],[93,39,"2019-02-26",26],[79,40,"2019-02-20",82],[35,127,"2019-03-14",63],[94,28,"2019-03-08",83],[61,11,"2019-02-07",1],[66,48,"2019-01-25",55],[76,156,"2019-02-02",67],[41,106,"2019-01-01",37],[37,148,"2019-03-21",7],[78,129,"2019-02-13",86],[21,133,"2019-03-04",64],[99,56,"2019-01-17",46],[98,20,"2019-01-26",31],[65,29,"2019-03-05",15],[70,79,"2019-03-30",97],[76,1,"2019-01-06",43],[36,58,"2019-03-02",76],[99,19,"2019-01-14",27],[56,77,"2019-01-19",36],[12,7,"2019-02-26",19],[23,187,"2019-02-18",93],[11,167,"2019-02-16",90],[22,64,"2019-02-27",23],[21,52,"2019-01-03",33],[59,138,"2019-01-21",65],[72,164,"2019-02-10",77],[6,92,"2019-03-21",61],[98,8,"2019-02-11",12],[70,180,"2019-03-12",2],[12,5,"2019-01-30",6],[48,132,"2019-02-15",88],[47,110,"2019-02-09",86],[64,96,"2019-02-03",51],[1,133,"2019-02-15",18],[6,121,"2019-03-01",62],[70,151,"2019-01-12",98],[58,197,"2019-02-10",96],[8,133,"2019-01-06",65],[52,124,"2019-02-23",91],[83,118,"2019-02-03",25],[39,188,"2019-01-03",36],[26,28,"2019-03-27",70],[92,68,"2019-03-03",53],[51,190,"2019-02-23",60],[91,180,"2019-02-21",27],[34,181,"2019-03-24",8],[77,91,"2019-01-14",41],[5,59,"2019-03-26",86],[89,116,"2019-03-27",63],[9,94,"2019-03-10",87],[71,173,"2019-01-26",43],[3,131,"2019-03-08",77],[84,133,"2019-03-11",3],[46,83,"2019-03-11",11],[49,199,"2019-01-26",34],[30,76,"2019-02-16",34],[20,156,"2019-02-06",89],[23,108,"2019-01-01",23],[47,69,"2019-02-13",93],[60,63,"2019-03-15",44],[85,99,"2019-02-27",45],[78,34,"2019-01-16",87],[58,31,"2019-02-25",52]]}}
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the order by

in the first case you don't have an order, so you don't have the partition ordered, in the second case you give the the hole an order and it will show the correct
result.

in short do following

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT PLAYER_ID FROM (
    SELECT 
        PLAYER_ID,
        EVENT_DATE,
        LEAD(EVENT_DATE,1) OVER(PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) AS NEXT_DAY,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PLAYER_ID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) AS LOGIN_RANK 
        FROM ACTIVITY) A
    WHERE NEXT_DAY - EVENT_DATE = 1
    AND LOGIN_RANK=1  
)
```